# about getlist and getvalue with cgi and forms

Tags: python, forms, cgi

I am working on a cgi script that is dealing with forms , in each form ,I have options as lists and radio buttons. The following one (third_form) is working fine because both task1 and task 2 are drop-down lists in the third form.

```py
if akey == "task1" or akey == "task2" or akey =="execute":
    third_form[akey] = elements.getlist(akey)
```

On the other hand , the second form has two lists for task 1 and task 2 and radio buttons for colors . getvalue is not working here and I can not get all selected values :
what is the mistake in the following?

```py
if akey == "color[]" or akey == "execute" or akey == "task1" or akey=="task2":
    second_form[akey] = elements.getvalue(akey)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks .. I found that It's working properly . The problem was probably with the form itself.